# Good pattern for grades with different grade systems

Tags: design-patterns

I'm making a system that has Exams that can be graded, but the catch is that they can be graded in different grading systems (like A, B, C, D... or percentages or the 12, 10, 7, 4, 02, 00 system we use in Denmark).

I will need some way of doing statistics on the grades, so they cannot simply be stored as Strings.

I want to be able to make new grading systems easily.

I was considering making a IGradeSystem interface and a Grade class (that references the IGradeSystem). That way I can simply make new implementations of the interface for new grade systems. But I don't know if this is a good way to do it.

Any pointers to what pattern I should be using? I'm sure there is a good/accepted way of doing this, and I prefer using patterns when there is one applicable.

Comment: Do you need statistics across multiple grade systems ? i.e. grades should be convertible ?

Comment: Yes, I think that will be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `IGradeSystem` solution is a good start. You can use it as a kind of Strategy/Policy design pattern inside a `Grade` to convert that grade to other systems. Generics are a good way of abstracting out both the type of value that the grade has (integer, letter, etc.) and the grade system it's in.

Rather than having an omniscient Strategy that can convert from any grade system to any other, I would create a common grade system that can act as a pivot between compatible grade systems. If all grade systems know how to convert a value in their realm to and from the common system, the convert operation could be as simple as :

```
TargetGradeSystem.From(MyGradeSystem.To(CommonGradeSystem))
```

Here's a unit test showing how it could be used from a client code perspective :

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GradeTest()
    {
        var grade1 = new CharacterGrade('A', GradeSystems.Letters);
        var grade2 = new NumericGrade(100, GradeSystems.Percentage);

        Assert.AreEqual(grade2.Value, grade1.To<int, PercentageGradeSystem>().Value);
    }
```

Grade system types could be defined like these, allowing for minimal friction when adding a new system :

```
public abstract class GradeSystem<TValue, TCommon>
{
    public abstract Grade<TCommon, TCommon> ToCommon(TValue value);
    public abstract Grade<TValue, TCommon> FromCommon(Grade<TCommon, TCommon> common);
}

public class LetterGradeSystem : GradeSystem<char, int>
{
    // assuming Percentage is the common system
    public override Grade<int, int> ToCommon(char value)
    {
        var index = char.ToUpper(value) - 64;
        return new Grade<int, int>(100 - ((1 - index) * 20), GradeSystems.Percentage);
    }

    public override Grade<char, int> FromCommon(Grade<int, int> common)
    {
        var character = (char)(common.Value + 64);
        return new Grade<char, int>(character, GradeSystems.Letters);
    }
}
```

I created a gist with the rest of the code if you want to have a look at it : https://gist.github.com/infosaurus/18d216ddf471c9619f7d

Comment: Wow, this is a nice and thorough answer :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

These are just scales that have a minimum value, a maximum value, and a way to convert the "raw value" to a human-readable one.

Let's say you have a generic class that stores a grade in a float number from 0 to 1, then subclasses have a method to convert the float number to a "grade system":

- multiply by 100 -> percentage
- multiply by 20 then round to the nearest .5 -> French marks (0 to 20)
- multiply by 5, round, then assign letters in reverse order (A=5, B=4, ..., F=0)

Comment: Hm, I guess I could do that (although the Danish system is really hard to convert since the spacing isn't even). Should they be subclasses or interface realizations?

Comment: Depends of the best practices / common design patterns of the language you're using. Being an Objective-C guy I would use classic subclassing, maybe with an abstract top-level class if your language has them.

Comment: Currently in C# but I'm mostly used to Java.

Comment: Seems like you might want a table of values. Let's say you can get a percentage score on a given test, and we always round to an integer. Therefore you have a range from 0 to 100. So Column 1 has 0 to 100; Column 2 has the equivalent string value for US, Column 3 has Denmark's, Column 4 France's, etc. This way you can just lookup the right way to report with a percentage score and a target country. No dependencies on the scales or ranges for anything.